# Preview mode show data byt publish shows no data

Tags: google-app-maker

I have finally connected my default Google SQL database to my AppMaker and I have imported my data. I have built a very simple view and it shows my data. When I preview my app it shows all my data. When I publish it, it does not show any data

I have changed the access mode and publish as user or publish as me, but it has no effect

The preview should be just like the publish, right? what is the point of having a preview that looks different from production. Why is it not showing my data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my deployment have no data but my preview has all the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55803032/why-does-my-deployment-have-no-data-but-my-preview-has-all-the-data)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to tell it that both the preview AND the production versions use your custom sql database.